# Laravel render problems 'foreach' loop

Tags: php, html, laravel, foreach, laravel-5

I have a funny problem with Laravel 5.2. I have a chunck of text that I'm trying to display with some explodes. The problem is that Laravel is rendering a bit strange, putting some wrong '**:**' before the end of the foreach loop.

This is the code sample from blade template:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
  @foreach(explode('),',$items[0]->chunk) as $text)
    <li>{{ str_replace('(',' : ',str_replace(')','',$text) }}</li>
  @endforeach
</ul>
```

And this is the version that Laravel is rendering for it:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
  <?php foreach(explode('),',$items[0]->chunck): ?> as $text)
    <li><?php echo e(str_replace('(',' : ',$text)); ?></li>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

I'm using NetBeans 8.0.2 as code editor (if that matters). Is there any problem with my code?

**Note:** If I manually edit the rendered view and move the ending PHP tag after `foreach` like so...

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
  <?php foreach(explode('),',$items[0]->chunck) as $text): ?>
    <li><?php echo e(str_replace('(',' : ',$text)); ?></li>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

...it works perfectly!

**Edit:** It seems to be a problem reading my ')' inside explode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write your loop as below:-

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
<?php $array = explode("),",$items[0]->chunk); ?>
  @foreach($array as $text)
    <li>{{ str_replace('(',' : ',str_replace(')','',$text) }}</li>
  @endforeach
</ul>
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: I would personally also do the exploding in the controller and avoid logic in the view so you just iterate over the array in the view.